# parse nested xml with php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Hello i am trying to parse nested xml but i am using multiple for loops to extact but i dont find it very proper way.

I want to parse data based on unique id and separte them but cant figure any easy way to that

here is my xml

```
<propertyList date="2014-06-02-17:30:33" username="adsss" password="v147C0z5CBlw">

<business modTime="2014-06-02-12:22:32" status="current">

<agentID>TEST</agentID>

<uniqueID>1420648</uniqueID>

<listingAgent id="1">

<name>jonny</name>

<telephone type="BH"></telephone>

<telephone type="mobile"></telephone>

<email>aT@cs.com.au</email>

</listingAgent>

<listingAgent id="2"></listingAgent>


</business>

<business modTime="2014-05-16-15:11:41" status="current">

<agentID>TEST</agentID>

<uniqueID>1435201</uniqueID>

<listingAgent id="1">

<name>Mike Smith</name>

<telephone type="BH"></telephone>

<telephone type="mobile"></telephone>

<email>acebrokers@bs.com.au</email>

</listingAgent><listingAgent id="2"></listingAgent>

</business>



</propertyList>
```

Here is my code

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("myxmldata.xml");
echo "<pre>";


for($i=0;$i<count($xml);$i++):

echo "agentID=>".$xml->business[$i]->agentID;

echo "<br>";

echo "uniqueID=>".$xml->business[$i]->uniqueID;

echo "<br>";

endfor;


for($i=0;$i<count($xml->business->listingAgent);$i++):

  echo "agentName=>".$xml->business->listingAgent[$i]->name;

endfor;

for($i=0;$i<count($xml->business->listingAgent->telephone);$i++):

  echo "telephonetype=>".$xml->business->listingAgent->telephone[$i]->type;

endfor;


?>
```

Comment: looks ok what you facing issue or what is expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("myxmldata.xml");

$data = array();
foreach($xml->business as $business) {
    $business = (array) $business;
    if (!array_key_exists($business['uniqueID'], $data)) {
        $listingAgent = (array) $business['listingAgent'];
        $data[$business['uniqueID']] = array(
            'agentID' => $business['agentID'],
            'uniqueID' => $business['uniqueID'],
            'name' => (string)$listingAgent[0]->name,
            'telephone' => (string) $listingAgent[0]->telephone[0],
            'mobile' => (string) $listingAgent[0]->telephone[1],
            'email' => (string) $listingAgent[0]->email,
        );
    }
}
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: HI manoj i want to extract them in plain array format.its very nested like name,email,telephone number of a an agent.

Comment: Answer updated for that, you need to store the values you want in array foramat

Comment: awesome...manoj.I was trying foreach loop but did not try $business = (array) $business.This works fine...Thanks

Comment: just one query manoj why we check array key exist ind data array? array_key_exists($business['uniqueID'], $data).what error will come if i dont write it?

Comment: It prevent duplicate entry with same `uniqueID`, if you are sure that there is no duplicate entry or you don't care about duplicate entry then you can remove it, to do so remove `if (!array_key_exists($business['uniqueID'], $data)) {` and it's closing `}` and change `$data[$business['uniqueID']] = array(` to `$data[] = array(`